# SEND SMS from samsung galaxy win celphone using vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

How to send sms from your cellphone to any number using vb.net? I have searched over the internet including youtube but it seems that i could not find or cant figure out where to start. My CP cant event detected in the "phone and modem" in windows...

Answer (score 0):

I have a perfect way to send SMS in visual basic, using AT-commands.

AT-commands:are instructed through which you can send and receive SMS messages, make calls from cell phone, and this is an example to Send a message:

Firstly:
Write this code in the top:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO
```

Secondly:

Write this code in the public class of form:

```
Dim SerialPort As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort()
Dim CR As String
```

Thirdly:

Create a textBox(TextmsgTextBox) to write the text message, and TextBox2(MobileNumberTextBox) to enter the mobile number, and Button(SendBUT) to Send message.

And write this code in the button click event.

```
 If SerialPort.IsOpen Then
        SerialPort.Close()
    End If
 SerialPort.PortName = COM4
    SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
    SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
    SerialPort.DataBits = 8
    SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
    SerialPort.DtrEnable = True
    SerialPort.RtsEnable = True
    SerialPort.NewLine = vbCrLf
    Dim message As String
    message = MsgRichTextBox.Text
    SerialPort.Open()
    If SerialPort.IsOpen() Then
        SerialPort.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
        SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
        SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & phoneNumBox.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
        SerialPort.Write(message & Chr(26))
        SentPicture.Visible = True
        SentLabel.Visible = True
        SentTimer.Start()
    Else
        MsgBox("Port not available")
    End If
```

I Hope My Answer Was Useful To You.

Answer (score 0):

**Important Note**

Port value change from time to another and from computer to another.

I will show you how to know port value of your device by pictures.

1:Enter to Device Manager from Control Panel.

[image]

2:Right click on the device, and choose Properties.
[image]

3:Choose Modem tap, and look for port name, and use it in your application.
[image]